# Unlimited quota for unauthenticated API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm creating an API using the 1.10.0 new Rest API. Below are some of the parameters I'm sending:

```
    body.setTransport(createList("http", "https"));
    body.setApiDefinition("{\"paths\":{\"/*\":{\"post\":{\"x-auth-type\":\"None\",\"responses\":{\"201\":{\"description\":\"Created\"}},\"x-throttling-tier\":\"Unlimited\"},\"get\":{\"x-auth-type\":\"None\",\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"OK\"}},\"x-throttling-tier\":\"Unlimited\"},\"delete\":{\"x-auth-type\":\"None\",\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"OK\"}},\"x-throttling-tier\":\"Unlimited\"},\"put\":{\"x-auth-type\":\"None\",\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"OK\"}},\"x-throttling-tier\":\"Unlimited\"}}},\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"" + providerApi.getName() + "\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\"}}");
    body.setTiers(createList("Unlimited"));
    body.setVisibility(VisibilityEnum.PUBLIC);
    body.setVisibleRoles(createList());
```

So the API is created as Unlimited/PUBLIC.

I changed all three default tiers configuration files:

```
./opt/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/resources/default-tiers/default-res-tiers.xml
./opt/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/resources/default-tiers/default-app-tiers.xml
./opt/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/resources/default-tiers/default-tiers.xml
```

To allow 10000 requests per minute for Unauthenticated role.

```
        <throttle:ID throttle:type="ROLE">Unauthenticated</throttle:ID>
        <wsp:Policy>
            <throttle:Control>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <throttle:MaximumCount>10000</throttle:MaximumCount>
                    <throttle:UnitTime>60000</throttle:UnitTime>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </throttle:Control>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

Yet after sending 60 requests per minute - the API is responded with status code 429 and error log indicate that quota exceeded...

After each change I re-started the APIM gateway and re-created the API's, just in case.

Any idea why the 10000 limit is not honored by the gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Manager will read those file on the very first up of the server and copied the content to registry, there after, API Manager won't check these files for any updates.

You have to update your policies in the registry.

Use the Registry browser through Management Console and navigate to following location `/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata`. You can see the tier xml file.

1. Log in to APIM management console (https://:9443/carbon) and select Browse under Resources

   [image]
2. Nagigate to /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata
3. You will see app-tiers.xml, res-tiers.xml, tiers.xml.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Where is the registry stored? Any way to access it not from console UI?

Comment: You can access the registry through WSO2 admin services SOAP APIs

Comment: I have error in between the response stating connection **#0 to hose localhost left intact**. Could you please help me ?